# Given $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, why is it true $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)}{\tan x} = \lim_{\tan x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan x)}{\tan x}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, why is it true $\lim_{x\to
> > 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))}{\tan(x)} = \lim_{\tan(x)\to
> > 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}=1$?

I know the theorem that sates that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$; nonetheless, I have seen numerous times that, given a function $f$ for which this works, they do something like $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}=1$, the last time I saw something like this is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))}{\tan(x)} = \lim_{\tan(x)\to 0}\frac{\sin(\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}=1$.

I want to know how can I apply this in general, correctly, since up until now, I've applying it informally kind of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\text{something in terms of $x$})}{\text{same something in terms of $x$}}=1$.

Could you help me with this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true in general that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, and $f(x)\neq0$ close to $a$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}=1
$$
This is rather straightforward to prove from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits.

For your special case, we have $f(x)=\tan(x)$ and $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$ and if $f$ is not locally 
constant i.e. 
$$\exists  \delta >0: \forall  x\in (a-\delta ,a+\delta )\setminus \{a\}, f(x)\neq \ell,$$
 then $$\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))=\lim_{y\to \ell}g(y).$$

Applying this to $g(y)=\frac{\sin(y)}{y}$ and $f(x)=\tan(x)$, allow you to conclude.

Comment: @Arthur: yes, you right. Thank you. (I edited).

Answer (score 0):

You could use L'Hôpital's rule.   Get $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac {\cos (\tan t)\cdot \sec^2 t}{\sec^2 t}=\lim_{t\to0}\cos (\tan t)=\cos\lim_{t\to0}\tan t=\cos (\tan 0)=\cos 0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the theorem you want is $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = 1$ and then take $u = \tan x$.